# Apple pay is not in my app

Tags: ios

I added apple pay capability support in my app. I was follow all the integration process of stripe. While using apple pay it shows the error   "Apple pay is not available in “App_Name”
Check the settings for this app and make sure it was designed to use apple pay"

Comment: Did you enable apple pay in project capabilities?

Comment: Is this in development, submitted to the store, in the simulator, has it ever worked, what are the provisioning profile details???